# NSPredicate traversing relationship (StackMob)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest, stackmob

I have been scouring Apple's Predicate Programming Guide and SO as well, trying to determine the correct way to write a predicate for a certain fetch request.

It seems like the way I am attempting to use dot notation to traverse a relationship is not being respected by the request.

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Task" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"project.user == %@", self.user];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
```

---

User, Project, and Task are all core data entities mapping to a BaaS provider (StackMob).

Relationships are as follows: **User** *one-to-many* **Project** *one-to-many* **Task** with inverse relationships as you would expect. What I am trying to do is get all tasks for the current logged in user. So, my thinking is: send a fetch request with the entity "Task". Where the project that owns the task is owned by the logged in user, get that task and display it. Simple enough.

And I think I *should* be able to use the dot notation in the predicate that I have shown above, but the fetch request is returning nil.

Everything else about the fetch request is fine. If I change the format string to `@"project != NULL"`, I get all of the tasks back.

Am I just writing my format string incorrectly? Is dot notation somehow not valid when sending a fetch request to StackMob?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if more information is needed. I'm a little too close to this right now to see it clearly.

Comment: I have no experience with StackMob, but your predicate looks good to me, and dot syntax is definitely allowed in predicates. Are you sure that `self.user` is an instance of the "User" entity?

Comment: @Martin R, thanks for your comment. Yes, when I log the predicate to the console, it prints: project.user == <User: 0x786bb70> (entity: User; id: 0x7c4c1a0 <x-coredata://C4FE9461-D49D-4E1D-B7AD-DB03F90946E4-1270-0000050B7FF5C142/User/pusername> ; data: {
    projects =     (
        "0x7d495b0 <x-coredata://C4FE9461-D49D-4E1D-B7AD-DB03F90946E4-1270-0000050B7FF5C142/Project/pf03c3074539c43faa729ea455934910b>"
    );
    username = username;
    usernameId = nil;
})

And I was just testing dot notation in a different application with a local data store. Worked fine.

Comment: What happens if you fetch all objects and then filter the array using `NSArray *filtered = [results filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]` ?

Comment: Yes, that is a valid workaround. Filtering the returned array with the same predicate gives me the result set I want. Querying for all tasks and then filtering them on the client side seems to pose a scalability issue. But this is in prototype stage right now, so maybe that's fine.

Comment: Normally, both methods should work and return the same results. But there was a similar problem a while ago here on SO, where filtering during the fetch did not work. I only remember that in that case also a non-standard backend was used.

Comment: @Martin R. Thanks for your assistance. It has been suggested (elsewhere) that I should just give my tasks a user ID instead of traversing the relationship with projects.

Comment: As I said, it does work with a "normal" local SQLite based backend. So this might be a special StackMob problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fetching on an attribute of a relationship (task where project.user == X) is not supported by StackMob.  However, it looks like you are trying to get all the tasks for a given project for the logged in user.  If I am correct in assuming that the logged in user was the one to create the projects and tasks, then set the permissions of the project schema to "Allow to sm_owner".  You can then fetch tasks based on the project ID (task where project IN 1234), or project based on ID and grab all tasks (project where projectId == 1234 and use value of tasks relationship).  Either way, with that permission fetches will only return results where sm_owner == logged in user, so you don't need to set up the fetch such that it uses the user ID as a filter.  Hope that helps!