# Core-Data: Predicate for To-Many Relationships to get Object in many related table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

In Deals Table the attributes:

```
ispopular(attribute)
groupname(attribute)
dealsassets(relationship-name to assets)
```

In Assets Table the attributes are :

```
assettype(attribute)
caption(attribute)
dealassetid(attribute)
assetsdeal(inverse relationshipname to deals)
```

Deals is Assets one to many relationship & Assets to Deals many to one relatiosnhip

I want to write a query where i need is `ispopular == 1 then that related field's assets.dealasseti`,

what predicate query i have to write, could some one help me out.

regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Assets"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"assetsdeal.ispopular == 1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Using the inverse relationship you ask for all assets where the related deal has the property "ispopular == 1".

---

**Alternative Solution** (if the first one does not work due to some StackMob restrictions):
Fetch the deals with "ispopular == 1" first:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Deals"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ispopular == 1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSError *error;
NSArray *deals = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

and use Key-Value Coding to get the related assets:

```
NSArray *assets = [deals valueForKeyPath:@"dealsassets.@distinctUnionOfSets.self"]
```

Comment: @Firo: Both "=" and "==" work. But if you NSLog a predicate then "==" is displayed for the equality operator, so I tend to use that.

Comment: @MartinR : i am getting this crash log : Error fetching: Error Domain=HTTP Code=400 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (HTTP error 400.)" UserInfo=0xac6bb80 {error=Field assetsdeal.ispopular does not exist in assets}

Comment: @iOSDev: You said that the Assets entity has a relationship "assetsdeal" to Deals, and that Deals has a property "ispopular". Perhaps you can show the contents of Assets.h and Deals.h or show a screenshot of the Core Data properties. - And how is this related to HTTP ??

Comment: @MartinR : I have added the screenshot could u check it

Comment: @iOSDev: The model looks OK. But could it be **that you are using StackMob?** If yes, why didn't you tell us in your question? - I have no experience with StackMob, but according to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16112734/1187415, fetching on an attribute of a relationship is not supported.

Comment: @MartinR : Yeah i am using Stackmob, thinking that coredata and stackmob work in the same way, so how can u get the value.. is there any other option.

Comment: @iOSDev: (I should get extra points for guessing correctly :-) ... I have added an alternative solution. But as I said, I have no experience with StackMob therefore I cannot say if that will work or not.

Comment: @MartinR : That u deserve, I was taken back when u said about stackmob

Comment: @MartinR : I Have used the alternative solution which u said, this i have already tried, and fell to the same problem once again, i am getting this as my output http://pastebin.com/gLrapcQv

Comment: @iOSDev: Why the same problem? Previously you had a crash, and now you get some output! - And that output doesn't look so bad. `"{(\n)}",` looks like the output from deal without any asset. Did you try `[deals valueForKeyPath:@"dealsassets.@distinctUnionOfSets.self"]` as suggested in my answer?

Comment: @MartinR : No, I have tried with this NSArray *assets = [deals valueForKeyPath:@"dealsassets.dealassetid"];

Comment: @MartinR: I have tried with this just now, [deals valueForKeyPath:@"dealsassets.@distinctUnionOfSets.self"], got the result http://pastebin.com/rf3bCWgU, I am getting the objects of Assets table, i need previoous output only, and if u see in this  pastebin.com/gLrapcQv in the last, we have some urls present, i need to put all those urls in array.

Comment: @iOSDev: So you need only the list of asset ids? Try `[deals valueForKeyPath:@"dealsassets.@distinctUnionOfSets.dealassetid"]`.

Comment: @MartinR : This Superb thanks a Lot Man... and Martin could you just throw some light what [deals valueForKeyPath:@"dealsassets.@distinctUnionOfSets.dealassetid"] does ??

Comment: @MartinR : We should also consider the performance right?, I am getting the required output, the performance is getting low, its taking time to get all the urls.. can we do anything to reduce this ??

Comment: @iOSDev: For `@distinctUnionOfSets`, have a look at the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1). I do not have a good idea for performance improvements, in particular because that might be a StackMob issue and I don't have any knowledge about StackMob. May I suggest that you start a new question dedicated to that problem? Then other people (who might know more about StackMob) will see it and can provide an answer.